# Не отрисовывается панель в java

Tags: java, алгоритм, структуры

Есть 3 класса, PanelEntryWindow вызывается в FrameEntryWindow, в свою очередь FrameEntryWindow вызывается в Entry Window, а EntryWindow в Main. Проблема в следующем - при запуске программы не отображается панель с кнопками, текстовыми полями и лейблами.

Main

```
import View.EntryWindow;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntryWindow.startEntryWindow();

}

}
```

EntryWindow

```
package View;

import javax.swing.*;

public class EntryWindow extends JFrame {

 public static void startEntryWindow(){

    FrameEntryWindow.FrameEntryWindow();

}
}
```

FrameEntryWindow

```
package View;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameEntryWindow extends JFrame {

protected static JFrame jFrame = new FrameEntryWindow();

static JFrame FrameEntryWindow(){

    jFrame = new JFrame("My Data Base");
    jFrame.setSize(250, 350);
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jFrame.setResizable(false);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.add(new PanelEntryWindow());
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    return jFrame;

}
}
```

PanelEntryWindow

```
package View;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class PanelEntryWindow extends JPanel {

private JLabel labelLogin = new JLabel("Login");
public JTextField inputLogin = new JTextField();

private JLabel labelPassword = new JLabel("Password");
public JTextField inputPassword = new JTextField();

public static JButton logInButton = new JButton("Login");

public static JButton newUserButton = new JButton("Create new user");

public PanelEntryWindow(){

    labelLogin.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 50);
    add(labelLogin);

    inputLogin.setBounds(50, 110, 150, 50);
    add(inputLogin);

    labelPassword.setBounds(50, 130, 100, 50);
    add(labelLogin);

    inputPassword.setBounds(50, 190, 150, 50);
    add(inputPassword);

    logInButton.setBounds(100, 230, 80, 50);
    add(logInButton);

    newUserButton.setBounds(50, 290, 200, 50);
    add(newUserButton);

}

}
```

Структура такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в корректировке размера для панели. Если в коде установишь главное окно resizable в true и растянешь окно - увидишь свою панель. Решение здесь простое - не устанавливать размер окна вручную, а использовать метод pack().

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: А можно было сделать как-то чтобы установить свой размер окна? Или нужно будет всегда задавать координатами в setBounds()?

Comment: @Илья метод setSize(int, int) если ты об этом.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что когда в Frame я добавляю в конце метод pack(), он делает окно ровно такого размера, чтобы поместились все элементы, делая окно небольшим. Мне хотелось бы оставить расстояние от краев окна до элементов, если я сначала установлю метод setSize(), а ниже pack(), то будет тот же результат, что и при отсутствии метода setSize(). Вопрос в том, как сделать окно определенного своего размера и чтобы отображались элементы?

Comment: @Илья подгоняй вручную размер окна и используй layout'ы. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Спасибо, пошел учить layout`ы